# UIGestestureReconizer on UIBarButtonItem in a translucent toolbar

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have some UIBarButtonItems with some gesture recognisers on them:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(undoButtonLongPress:)];
[[undoButton valueForKey:@"view"]addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Everything works as expected but when I make the toolbar translucent in my storyboard, the gesture recognisers don't fire the events.
How should I use gesture recognisers on a translucent toolbar?